# Stuck on playing wav file in java... Need some guidance

Tags: java, audio, wav

I'm trying to play sound in java when a button is pressed. So I have something like the following:

```
public void playSound(File soundFile) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Then I call the method in actionPerformed inside buttonListener:

```
playSound(new File("woow_x.wav"));
```

But it's throwing UnsupportedAudioFileException. Is this saying that .wav files are not supported? I confirmed that the wav file works so I don't know what the issue is. And I'm trying to do this without using sun. Please let me know how this is correctly done. Thank you.

Stack trace:

```
    javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input 
    stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at robotMaze.SystemGUI.playSound(SystemGUI.java:183)
    at robotMaze.SystemGUI$SendButtonListener.actionPerformed(SystemGUI.java:229)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}`: don't do this, otherwise you don't know what the problem is. At least do `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Then copy and paste the stack trace here.

Comment: Done. Is this saying that .wav files are unsupported?

Comment: More likely some particular aspect of your file. Try `System.out.println(AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(soundFile).getFormat());` and tell us what it says.

Comment: `javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type`

Comment: Where did you get the wav file? Do you know anything about its encoding?

Comment: I got it from wavesource.com. I'm really not sure what the issue is... The file works fine when I play it using an audio player.

Comment: Do you have a link to the file? My line of thinking is that it has an unusual encoding. (Wav is not just LCPM.) Either that or the JDK for your OS behaves differently from mine.

Comment: [link](http://www.wavsource.com/sfx/sfx3.htm) I right clicked on one of the files to save it into my directory. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's encoding is specified in its header to be `0x55`. I'm not sure exactly what `0x55` is, but I suspect it is mp3. Either way, it's not one of the encodings supported by Java.

For your purposes (and if the license allows it), you might use an audio editor to convert the file to a format that is supported. (These are enumerated by the static fields in [`AudioFormat.Encoding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.Encoding.html).)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Any way you can quickly help me on how to use AudioFormat.Encoding? I don't know what any of that field is (ulaw, alaw etc.). Thank you for being so helpful! I really appreciate it.

Comment: AudioFormat.Encoding is basically an enum of the formats javax.sound.sampled supports. If you convert the file with an audio editor, you can choose any of those formats. If you don't know what A-law, u-law, PCM, etc is, you should Google it because there are Wikipedia articles and such. ; ) PCM is the simplest format. A very standard format is 16-bit PCM with a sample rate of 44,100Hz.

Comment: Yup, `0x55` is the [TwoCC](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/TwoCC) code for mp3.